# Line wrapping bug on Achievements menu

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog

Most things line wrap on my Achievements menu, but [this question title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309241/this-asynctask-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur) doesn't.

[image]

Even when it is down lower on the list, it still doesn't line wrap. Things above and below it do.

**Update**

It is still happening. And only for this particular question. I checked out the title characters [here](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/), but I didn't see anything strange.

Comment: They used non-breaking spaces in the title. I edited it to replace them, but there's already another question with that exact title, so I changed it slightly.

Comment: @MikeM. That's weird. I thought I had checked for that. Anyway, that fixed it. Thanks.